# Using primary tabs using jetpack compose

Tags: android, tabs, android-jetpack-compose

I'm just wondering if primary tabs are possible using jetpack compose?

If not, is it reasonable to inflate an xml with primary tabs?

https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/overview#42aff813-9141-464d-b00e-d4fdb585c2cb

I tried looking up resources/implementations but couldn't find any regarding primary tabs. I tried implementing it as secondary tabs which worked but they aren't meant for what I am planning to do according to Google (and also don't look modern)

Comment: https://www.composables.com/components/material3/tab -- `Tab()` offers a slot for an icon.

Comment: Yes, those are secondary tabs

Comment: Secondary tabs don't have icons. Where does the icon show up on a `Tab()`?

Comment: Exactly and the link you shared doesn't have icons. wdym

Comment: Presumably Alex's demo did not use the `icon` slot parameter. Have you tried using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with Abhimanyu's answer, it's not possible to use the primary indicator look unless you use 1.2 alpha.

> Deprecate Indicator and add Primary/SecondaryIndicator to match the M3
> specs. PrimaryIndicator matches the width of the tab's content whereas
> SecondaryIndicator spans the full available width. SecondaryIndicator
> is equivalent to the now deprecated Indicator and can be a direct
> replacement

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3

In Gradle, you need to use:

```
androidx.compose.material3:material3-*:1.2.0-alpha03
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if that works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The primary Tab in Jetpack compose for reference,

[image]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Tab
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRow
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults.tabIndicatorOffset
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun PrimaryTabRowDemo() {
    var periodIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val periodLabels = listOf(
        "Upcoming",
        "Past",
    )

    TabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = periodIndex,
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            if (periodIndex < tabPositions.size) {
                TabRowDefaults.PrimaryIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[periodIndex]),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 3.dp,
                        topEnd = 3.dp,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                    ),
                )
            }
        },
    ) {
        periodLabels.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                selected = periodIndex == index,
                onClick = {
                    periodIndex = index
                },
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It motivates me to continue :)

I get the error "Unresolved reference: PrimaryIndicator". Do you have an idea if I forgot to import something? Or do you have the definition of that?

Comment: @Pablo, Added import statements

Comment: Thanks! For some odd reason I still get the same error tho. I imported everything and it just won't work. I looked up [the google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TabRowDefaults) and it should be correct, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @Pablo you might have an older compose version, try updating to the latest version